# How to prevent flexbox from using entire max-height before wrapping items into next column?

Tags: html, css

I have a flexbox container that wraps in separate columns.

When it wraps, it leaves an extra little space below the bottom item of the far left column as demonstrated in the example below.

I'd like the space between the bottom blue rectangle and the bottom of the green div to be equivalent to the blue rectangle's margin, NOT the excess space from the green div's max height.

In my real world example, the blue rectangles have varying heights.  This is a simplified version of what my UI looks like.

Basically, instead of having the extra green at the bottom (marked by the red x), I want it to be flush with the bottom blue rectangle.

[image]

This is what the result would look like in theory:

[image]

This is my example HTML/CSS code that replicates the problem:

```css
/* Styles go here */

.FlexDiv{
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 100px;
    max-height:445px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    background-color: green;
}

.Rectangle{
    margin: 5px;
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 69px;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
    background-color:blue;
}

.LoadingText{
  position:relative;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

<div class="FlexDiv"> 
  <div class="Rectangle"></div>
  <div class="Rectangle"></div>
  <div class="Rectangle"></div>
  <div class="Rectangle"></div>
  <div class="Rectangle"></div>
  <div class="Rectangle"></div>
  <div class="Rectangle"></div>
  
</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?  Or is this not possible in the realm of Flexbox?

Comment: You use a fixed height - can you use `gap: 12px`? See https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-gap-space-with-flexbox

Comment: I tried that in my real world app, but it didn’t work.  According to your link, it should’ve worked.  This is a major cause of my confusion.

Comment: Check out the example below. It also adds up to 12px using margin and paddings. This looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code a bit. Someting like this would be helpful:

```
   .FlexDiv {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 445px;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    background-color: green;
}

.Rectangle {
    margin: 2px 5px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-height: 69px;
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    background-color: blue;
}
```